# Не получается создать запись в БД, Использован Hibernate

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

База данных с одной таблицей students ((int, primaryKey, autogenerated)Id, (varchar) FirstName, (varchar)LastName, (varchar)Group)

Тестовый класс

```
package DataBase.Tables;

import DataBase.Dao.StrudentsDAO;

/**
 * Created by Рабочий on 04.05.2016.
 */
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        StrudentsDAO stud = new StrudentsDAO();
        try {
            Students stude = new Students("Vladimir","Luchnikov","11i-13-14");
            stud.createStudent(stude);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

StrudentsDAO

```
package DataBase.Dao;

import DataBase.Tables.Students;
import org.hibernate.HibernateException;
import org.hibernate.Query;

/**
 * Created by Рабочий on 20.04.2016.
 */
//DAO для работы со студентами
public class StrudentsDAO extends DAO {

    //Создать студента
    public Students createStudent(Students stud) throws Exception {
            try {
                begin();
                Students students = new Students(stud);
                getSession().save(students);
                commit();
                return students;
            } catch (HibernateException e) {
                rollback();
                throw new Exception("Could not create student " + stud.getFirstName() + " " + stud.getLastName() + " ", e);
            }
        }

    public Students retrieveStudent(int studentId) throws Exception{
        try {
            begin();
            Query q = getSession().createQuery("from Students where id = :studentId");
            q.setInteger("studentId", studentId);
            Students stud = (Students) q.uniqueResult();
            commit();
            return stud;
        } catch (HibernateException e){
            rollback();
            throw new Exception("Could not get student with id" + studentId,e );
        }
    }

    //Удалить студента
    public void deleteStudent(Students student) throws Exception{
        try {
            begin();
            getSession().delete(student);
            commit();
        } catch (HibernateException e){
            rollback();
            throw new Exception("Could not delete student " + student.getFirstName() + " " + student.getLastName());
        }
    }
}
```

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>groupId</groupId>
    <artifactId>ServerDataBase</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>3.5.6-Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.38</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-c3p0</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>



    </dependencies>

</project>
```

StackTrace

```
мая 11, 2016 12:50:26 AM org.hibernate.Version logVersion
INFO: HHH000412: Hibernate Core {5.1.0.Final}
мая 11, 2016 12:50:26 AM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment <clinit>
INFO: HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
мая 11, 2016 12:50:26 AM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment buildBytecodeProvider
INFO: HHH000021: Bytecode provider name : javassist
мая 11, 2016 12:50:26 AM org.hibernate.annotations.common.reflection.java.JavaReflectionManager <clinit>
INFO: HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.0.1.Final}
мая 11, 2016 12:50:27 AM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl configure
WARN: HHH10001002: Using Hibernate built-in connection pool (not for production use!)
мая 11, 2016 12:50:27 AM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl buildCreator
INFO: HHH10001005: using driver [com.mysql.jdbc.Driver] at URL [jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/Teststud]
мая 11, 2016 12:50:27 AM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl buildCreator
INFO: HHH10001001: Connection properties: {user=root, password=****}
мая 11, 2016 12:50:27 AM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl buildCreator
INFO: HHH10001003: Autocommit mode: false
мая 11, 2016 12:50:27 AM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.PooledConnections <init>
INFO: HHH000115: Hibernate connection pool size: 20 (min=1)
Wed May 11 00:50:27 MSK 2016 WARN: Establishing SSL connection without server's identity verification is not recommended. According to MySQL 5.5.45+, 5.6.26+ and 5.7.6+ requirements SSL connection must be established by default if explicit option isn't set. For compliance with existing applications not using SSL the verifyServerCertificate property is set to 'false'. You need either to explicitly disable SSL by setting useSSL=false, or set useSSL=true and provide truststore for server certificate verification.
мая 11, 2016 12:50:27 AM org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect <init>
INFO: HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
мая 11, 2016 12:50:29 AM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper logExceptions
WARN: SQL Error: 1064, SQLState: 42000
мая 11, 2016 12:50:29 AM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper logExceptions
ERROR: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'Group, LastName) values (null, null, null)' at line 1
java.lang.Exception: Could not create student Vladimir Luchnikov 
    at DataBase.Dao.StrudentsDAO.createStudent(StrudentsDAO.java:23)
    at DataBase.Tables.Test.main(Test.java:13)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:140)
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute statement
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.convert(SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.java:63)
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:42)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:111)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:97)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:207)
    at org.hibernate.dialect.identity.GetGeneratedKeysDelegate.executeAndExtract(GetGeneratedKeysDelegate.java:57)
    at org.hibernate.id.insert.AbstractReturningDelegate.performInsert(AbstractReturningDelegate.java:42)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2827)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3398)
    at org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityIdentityInsertAction.execute(EntityIdentityInsertAction.java:81)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.execute(ActionQueue.java:597)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addResolvedEntityInsertAction(ActionQueue.java:232)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addInsertAction(ActionQueue.java:213)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addAction(ActionQueue.java:256)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.addInsertAction(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:318)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSaveOrReplicate(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:275)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:182)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:113)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.saveWithGeneratedOrRequestedId(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:192)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedOrRequestedId(DefaultSaveEventListener.java:38)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:177)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveEventListener.performSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveEventListener.java:32)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.onSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:73)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireSave(SessionImpl.java:682)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.save(SessionImpl.java:674)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.save(SessionImpl.java:669)
    at DataBase.Dao.StrudentsDAO.createStudent(StrudentsDAO.java:18)
    ... 6 more
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'Group, LastName) values (null, null, null)' at line 1
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:422)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:404)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:387)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:939)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3878)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3814)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2478)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2625)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2551)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:1861)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdateInternal(PreparedStatement.java:2073)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdateInternal(PreparedStatement.java:2009)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeLargeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:5094)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:1994)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:204)
    ... 28 more
```

Comment: `Group` - это ключевое слово в SQL, нельзя его использовать **как есть** в качестве имени поля/столбца.

Comment: Можно, если заключит в кавычки или какие-то другие знаки, которые приняты в mysql.

Comment: А яб попробовал переименовать, кто сказал что гиперсеть именно с кавычками передает?

Comment: Никто не говорил, что он передаёт именно с кавычками, Но у гибернета, как у долгожителя ORM, наверняка должна быть такая возможность. Кто сказал, что её нет?

Comment: @Lukashman маловато вы данных дали...На первый взгляд все благополучно, если учесть что в суперклассе DAO у вас организованно все правильно/если предположить что конструктор для сущности Студент наполняет поля и аннотации у вас верные... (К слову вы зачем передаете объект типа студент в метод и создаете еще один объект на базе предыдущего (у вас вообеще в классе Студент такой конструктор есть?)?) остается вариант с магией :/

Comment: Group нельзя было использовать, все работает, спасибо всем за ответы.